# ASP.NET MVC routing fails when using default.aspx/controller/action style url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, routes

I'm deploying an ASP.NET MVC site to a IIS6 webserver, so I'm using a *default.aspx/{controller}/{action}* style routing strategy.

However, for some reason it doesn't really work when using the default.aspx part. No matter the url, it always gets the default action (Index) on the default controller (Public).

I've been using the excellent [Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to see what's going on.

[route fail http://img169.yfrog.com/img169/7532/routefail.gif](http://img169.yfrog.com/img169/7532/routefail.gif)

As you can see I'm requesting *default.aspx/contact*, which should match the 3rd route in the table. 
Actually ANYTHING I write after *default.aspx/* matches the two last routes in the table (I understand the last one).

I'm getting this behavior on both Cassini and IIS6.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RouteTable.Routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

Now it works. 
Got the answer from [here](http://www.58bits.com/blog/2008/09/29/ASPNet-MVC-And-Routing-Defaultaspx.aspx).

I think this info should have been on the asp.net/mvc site, like [this page for instance](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-08-cs.aspx).