# Default page of MVC application not found when using .mvc.aspx in Route

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm trying to use ASP.NET MVC with older versions of IIS that have trouble with MVC's default routing.  I found a suggestion to add `.mvc.aspx` to my routes.  So instead of this:

```
    routes.MapRoute( _
        "Default", _
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
        New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", 
                  .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
    )
```

I now use this:

```
    routes.MapRoute( _
        "Default", _
        "{controller}.mvc.aspx/{action}/{id}", _
        New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", 
    )
```

This works at getting MVC to work on older versions of IIS.  However, when I navigate to `http://win2k3machine/MyMVCApplication/`, I get "Directory Listing Denied" message.  Similarly, when I use Casini (Visual Studio's development web server) and navigate to `http://localhost:2019`, I get a "Server Error in '/' Application." message.

What do I need to change in IIS and/or my MVC application to get the default page to work correctly?

*NOTE: I tried adding `RouteTable.Routes.RouteExistingFiles = True` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470613/asp-net-mvc-routing-fails-when-using-default-aspx-controller-action-style-url/1470918#1470918), but that didn't seem to fix the problem.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Wildcard mapping in IIS. Refer to this article for more details:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: This was really useful.  Unfortunately, I couldn't get the Wildcard mapping to work, but everything else in the article was very helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had difficulty getting Wildcard mapping to work in IIS 6.  However, adding a Default.aspx page with the following code fixed the issue:

VB.NET:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
  Handles Me.Load
    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath, False)
    Dim httpHandler As IHttpHandler = New MvcHttpHandler()
    httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current)
End Sub
```

C#:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{ 
    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath, false); 
    IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler(); 
    httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current); 
}
```

Olders versions of IIS want to see a Default.aspx page, so this page rewrites the path to work correctly.  If you get the Wildcard mapping to work in IIS, you don't need this page.